# matplotlib boxplot with extra whiskers at 5% from median

Tags: python, matplotlib

I used http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo2.html example to plot multiple boxes with `whis=1.5`

How can I add second set of whiskers at `+-5%` from median.

Answer (score 2):

There's no simple way at the moment. You could make individual calls to `plot` if you wanted.

In version 1.4 you'll be able to say:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.boxplot(data, ...) # normal boxplots
ax.boxplot(data, whis=[45,55], showboxes=False, showmedians=False, showfliers=False)
```

The second command will only draw whiskers at the 45th and 55th percentiles.

In case that's not what you meant, you'll be able to use `matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats(data)` to get a list of dictonaries. You can this modify the whisker elements of those dictionaries and feed the final version to `ax.bxp`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stats = matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats(data)
for s in stats:
    s['whislo'] = s['med'] * 0.95
    s['whishi'] = s['med'] * 1.05

ax.bxp(stats)
```

NOTE: in both cases, whiskers will still be drawn starting from the first and third quartiles for the lower and upper whiskers, respectively. In other words, they'll be facing *inward*.

Comment: Thank you for showing the use of boxplot_stats, I started from here and finally I could get to the documentation  (for whom is interested http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/bxp_demo.html )